# How to pass request.user with a ManyToMany Field in Django

Tags: django, validation, many-to-many, create-view

I have two models Exercise and Area, Area has a manytomanyfield back to Exercise:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Area(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exercise = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, blank=True)
```

I want the user to be able to create a new exercise that automatically attaches to its specific area, and also passes in request.user. Here is my view:

```
from .forms import ExerciseForm as e_form

class ExerciseFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = e_form
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        area = Area.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["area_id"])
        new_ex = Exercise.objects.latest('id')
        new_ex.user = self.request.user
        area.exercise.add(new_ex)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
      
        return JsonResponse({'exercise': model_to_dict(new_ex)}, status=200)
```

And its registered url:

```
path('exercise-add-new/<int:area_id>/', ExerciseFormView.as_view(), name='exercise_add_new'),
```

I should add that this used to work until I recently added `user` as a field to the Exercise model, and `new_ex.user = self.request.user` to the view. Now when I try to submit the form nothing happens. No errors, and no objects are created. I have tried `new_ex.user = self.request.user` and `form.instance.user = self.request.user` and still nothing happens.

Btw my user attributes are a ForeignKey to the auth user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**EDIT**

If I remove the `user` field from the Exercise model my view works, however I want to then be able to see details of each exercise, but have those details visible only to the user who created them. Is there another way that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

- I see you have involved user in both of the models. This shouldn't be done.
- You should user as Foreign Key in either of the Models not both. This would cause insolvency in your logic.
- You can do it with a simple logic like : Remove user Foreign Key from Exercise
- Models.py

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

- Views.py

```
from .forms import ExerciseForm as e_form

class ExerciseFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = e_form
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        area = Area.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
        new_ex = Exercise.objects.latest('id')
        area.exercise.add(new_ex)
        area.save()
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return JsonResponse({'exercise': model_to_dict(new_ex)}, status=200)
```

- To get all exercises of a specific user

```
a = Area.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
exercises = a.exercise.all()
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for responding. This method successfully saved the object to Exercise, however it didn't attach to the specific Area. And also, the reason I wanted to include a user in the Exercise is so that I can then display Exercise details only to the user who created them. I was going to use `{% if exercise.user.user == request.user %} for this. Or would it be possible another way?

Comment: I forgot to add the line ```area.save()```
Now it will work. It will attach exercise to the Area.

Comment: For getting the exercises of a specific user, you can simply get all the exercises of a specific area like 
```a = Area.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id).first()``` ->
```exercises = a.exercise.all()```

Comment: Ah ok, so I should add these two lines into my view? And how can I then access this in my template?

Comment: You can create a seperate view also or otherwise just pass exercise in context and display in html, you got that?

Comment: Sorry not fully, do you have time to take this to private chat?

Comment: I have a DetailView that displays the exercise detail. I tried inserting those lines in there under the `get_context_data` method like this `a = Area.objects.get(user__id=self.request.user.id).first()` `context['exercises'] = a.exercise.all()` but I get `MultipleObjectsReturned` error

Comment: sure let's talk over it on chat.

Comment: Thank you @Priyanshu Panwar but I think I have it sussed now

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a user field with a foreign key to Profile in my Workout model and then instantiate the view.